# how to rewrite "includes" command with raw MySQL?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, include

If I run the command

```
@users = User.includes(:addresses)
```

then are generated these two queries:

```
#  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" 
#  SELECT "addresses".* FROM "addresses" WHERE "addresses"."user_id" IN (1, 2)
```

Is there any way to this construction (`includes`) with pure MySQL? Something like:
`@users = User.find_by_sql("...")`?

Comment: Do you want this to be executed in a single query? The problem is a bit unclear.

Comment: Well, I am trying to execute the `includes` functionality in a single MySQL query. Ideally, to execute those two queries as a single one.

Comment: ...and how do intend to process different objects in one table? You will still get a single result set whatever you do.

Comment: By explicitly `JOIN`ing inside a `find_by_sql()`, you can get the associations in one query, but Rails will not build the models with associations, at least I don't know how to make it build them without another query. But all the requested attributes are already there in the result set.

Comment: @D-side that's the thing - I don't know yet, trying to figure out. I am trying to find out if there's any efficient way to execute the `includes` construction outside of ActiveRecord - through raw MySQL.

Comment: @fivedigit well... it is possible, it's not optimal though and is costly for Ruby to process. You'd need to get a table of objects with columns of both types, half of which will be `NULL` depending on what type of object that is.

Answer (score 0):

No, they're two queries with different result sets so you can't merge them in any useful way.

ActiveRecord is essentially doing this:

1. Execute the first query to get all the `User`s.
2. Pull the `User` `id`s out of the first result set to build the second query.
3. Execute the second query to get all the `Address`es associated with the `User`s from **1**.
4. Slice up the `Address`es by `user_id` and stash the pieces in the corresponding `User`s.

So all the `includes` is doing is expanding the association in one go instead of expanding the association user by user (i.e. one query per user, AKA `n+1`).

You're welcome to emulate what AR is doing on your own though but you'll still be doing two queries.

---

If you were using a database with array support (such as PostgreSQL) then you could do it in one query using an aggregate:

```
select u.*, array_agg(a.*)
from users u
left join addresses a on u.id = a.user_id
group by u.id, ...
```

That sort of thing will confuse ActiveRecord though and leave you to unpack the results by hand. I doubt the above would be any faster anyway.